# How to check whether a value exists in an array that is stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, select

I have a database where moments contain a user id and friend id's. The friend_ids are saved as an array. I have a page where all the moments should be displayed. I want to check for moments which contains a certain id. For example I made a moment my own so my id is in the field user_id but also a friend of mine created a moment and so I am in the friend_ids. Now I need to check on this page if my id occurs in the user_id or friend_ids table. How can I check if a value exist in an array in a database? Do I have to fetch all records and loop through them to check the arrays or is there a better method?

The array looks like this in the database:

```
[2,3]
```

And this is what my database schema looks like right now, i haven't set any relations between the tables yet. 
[image: This is how the database looks like right now]

Comment: How is this array represented in the database?

Comment: I added it to my question @Mureinik

Comment: It seems like you're designing your database in a bad way. Saving as array it is a bad idea especially when you try to apply conditions on such column.

You should consider many-to-many relationship (where you save the user_id and a friend_id in a pivot table). Are you able to change the DB structure?

Comment: Yes I am still able to change my database. Do you have any suggestions? @MyLibary

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand.
A moment is being created by a single user (which represented as the user_id), and a he can associate this moment with his friends (which stored in the friend_ids)?

Comment: Yes that's right @MyLibary

Comment: Could you just share the current table design so I can adjust it?

Comment: I added my current database design @MyLibary

Comment: Check my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Mureinik suggested, although he provided a solution to your question, you better represent your data better.
With time, moments friend_ids field will get really big and will affect the performance.

In the following diagram you could see how I took *_ids column and set a dedicated pivot table for each one, that way you can get your friends easily by adding a JOIN clause.

Try to read more about models or entities relationship (you may find good example in Laravel documentation)

[image: Database suggestion]

**If you have any question, let me know.**

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I understand the diagram and I think that this indeed solves my problem better than store arrays in the database. If I am right I can define relationships in Laravel right? Because this project is made with Laravel.

Comment: Yep you do, and it is pretty easy :) You're more than welcome

Comment: https://imgur.com/1P10ngu just to be sure, do I have to see it like this? And if so, do I have to set the relationships like they do here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships?

Comment: I think I have made a belongsToMany relationship between the users and moments. Any idea on how I can test of this works properly and to check if I did it right? @MyLibary

Answer (score 2):

As a general piece of advice, this isn't a great way to store things in a database. You'd probably be better off creating a junction table that holds the friendship status per pair of users.

If you can't do that, you could chop off the first and last characters (`[` and `]`), and use `find_in_set` on the remaining comma-delimited string:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  SELECT FIND_IN_SET(123, TRIM(TRAILING ']' FROM TRIM(LEADING '[' FROM friend_ids))) > 0
-- Just an example -------^
```

Comment: So a better way could also be to save the moment_id in the table users?